# Summing Different Values in For Loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

My code is below, what I want to do is get the 5 individual ft arrays and add them together inside the for loop so that I can play a sound of the superposition of them all. Thanks for any help!

```
`fs = 44100;  % standard sampling rate
T = 1/fs;    % sampling period
t = 0:T:5;   % time vector
conv = 1E5;  % conversion factor for frequencies

phi=2*pi*rand(1,1); % random phase

Msun = 2E30; % mass of the sun
Rsun = 6.9599E5; % radius of the sun
M = 1E32; % mass of target star
R = 7E5; % radius of target star
Teff = 6000;

% frequency of maximum oscillation mode

vmax  = 3090*(M/Msun)*(R/Rsun)^(-2) * (Teff/5777)^(-1/2);

% difference between consecutive frequencies

dv = 134.9*(M/Msun)^(1/2) * (R/Rsun)^(-3/2);


for n = 0:1:4

    vi = vmax + n.*dv; % pulsation mode frequencies
    ft = sin(2*pi.*vi.*t + phi); % sinusoidal perturbation function
    cft = conv.*ft; % converted perturbation for human audible range
    sound(cft, fs) % play sound of each frequency mode

end
```

`

Comment: i just test your code and it works I can hear the 5 different sound but the superposition , you don't add them together,  what about saving the in a matrix and than  hypermatrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the individual sounds to get a superposition. Just do `cft = 0;` before the loop, then `cft = cft + conv.*ft;` inside. After the loop, call `sound(cft, fs)`.

Comment: Ah, yes, should've thought of that. Thanks!